# How can I install nxt_python in ROS Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, package-management, ros

I have installed ROS fuerte and established a connection between the LEGO NXT and my PC's ROS through 2 terminals. I start ROS with the command `roscore`

The problem is that when I run a command to start some sensor of the LEGO, for exampled:

```
rosrun nxt_python touch_sensor_test.py
```

the terminal says:

```
[rospack] Error: stack/package nxt_python not found
```

And I can't do anything with the LEGO.

I have tried downloading [`nxt_python` for Ubuntu 12.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/precise/python/nxt-python) and tried to install it and it doesn't work.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to AU! Unfortunately your question is in a terrible state. It's very hard to understand, what the issue is. It appears, that you need to install the Python module `nxt_python` from the package `nxt-python`, but there seems to be some problem, that you don't mention. It's good to mention the overall purpose of your endeavour, but I think you spent far to much words on it compared to the actual problem. Please [edit] your question and try to cut down the borderline related parts and clarify the information on the core issue. See [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidFoerster any better now?

Comment: @Zanna: Thanks for the edit! The question is understandable now but it still lacks information, e. g. installation error messages.

Comment: @DavidFoerster agreed - I would have voted to close it as unclear, but you answered it...

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to have noticed yourself, you need the Python module `nxt_python` from the package `nxt-python`, which you can install with

```
sudo apt-get install nxt-python
```